# How can you change a ";" seperated string to some kind of dictionary?

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I have a string like this:
"user=u123;name=Test;lastname=User"

I want to get a dictionary for this string like this:

```
user     "u123"  
name     "Test"  
lastname "User"
```

this way I can easely access the data within the string.

I want to do this in C#.

EDIT:
This is what I have so far:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ValueToDictionary(string value)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> result = null;

    result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string[] values = value.Split(';');

    foreach (string val in values)
    {
        string[] valueParts = val.Split('=');
        result.Add(valueParts[0], valueParts[1]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

But to be honest I really think there is a better way to do this.

Cheers,
M.

Comment: It's not going to get any better than what you have now. At this time, the answers below are all far harder to read than your own code. The only real improvement you could make is make it faster (at the cost of making it even more unreadable than the current answers), but it probably doesn't need to be any faster?

Comment: Your code is good and readable, I prefer this solution over any LINQ solution.

Comment: As you've seen most solutions use split. One thought crossed my mind though, can you guarantee there will be no whitespace present? If so, you'll need to add some trimming logic or consider regex

Comment: +1 to the comments. They're right. Anything more automatic will be an already made function to separe that format. The only thing you can trim is assigning the "new Dict.." directly to the variable declaration :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string by ";".

Iterate over every element in the resulting array and split every element by "=".

Now;
dictionary.add(element[0], element[1]);

I Hope I made it clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ:

```
var text = "user=u123;name=Test;lastname=User";
var dictionary = (from t in text.Split( ";".ToCharArray() )
                  let pair = t.Split( "=".ToCharArray(), 2 )
                  select pair).ToDictionary( p => p[0], p => p[1] );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var linedValue = "user=u123;name=Test;lastname=User";
var kvps = linedValue.Split(new[] { ';' }); // you may use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
foreach (var kvp in kvps)
{
    var kvpSplit = kvp.Split(new[] { '=' });
    var key = kvpSplit.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
    var value = kvpSplit.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
    dictionary.Add(key, value);
    // you may check with .ContainsKey if key is already persistant
    // you may check if key and value with string.IsNullOrEmpty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string s1 = "user=u123;name=Test;lastname=User";
foreach (string s2 in s1.Split(';')) 
{
    string[] split = s2.Split('=');
    d.Add(split[0], split[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that there are no separator chars in your input data, the following works

```
string input = "user=u123;name=Test;lastname=User";
string[] fragments = input.Split(";=".ToArray());
Dictionary<string,string> result =  new Dictionary<string,string>()
for(int i=0; i<fragments.Length-1;i+=2)
  result.Add(fragments[i],fragments[i+1]);
```

It might perform slightly better than some of the other solutions, since it only calls Split() once. Usually I would go for any of the other solutions here, especially if readability of the code is of any value to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do it like this...

```
String s = "user=u123;name=Test;lastname=User";
Dictionary<string,string> dict = s.ToDictionary();
```

The implementation of ToDictonary is the same as yours except that I would implement it as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). It does look more natural.